# How do you reach the command line on a android phone?

Tags: connection-issues

I have been reading about all the things that can be done with an android if you can reach the command line in the OS Shell. I'm working with an old LGL55CV3 in hope that I can network it to my Raspberry B+ with the ARM7 chip. I'm a NOOB but, I'm moving to the JavaScript OS chip as soon as I can unlock the command line to the LG.

Comment: How do you want to network it with Pi? You can run ADB in wireless mode (Pi then needs to run an ADB server and compatible ADB client) on Android and access it from Pi, or you can run an [SSH server](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ssh) on Android then access it using Pi. In any case, consider clarifying the situation and tell us what have you tried so far to answer your own question.

Comment: Thanks Firelord. What I'd like to do is discover a way to us the LGL55CV3 as my screen and keypad. Then perhaps go online with it. Currently I'm working on setting up a battery system so my Pi B+ can go mobile. But, if I have the drag around a full-size keyboard and mouse it defeats the purpose.

Comment: Firelord thanks for the information I consider the question answered. It opens up new questions. But, I'm sure if I keep looking I will find how to root the LGL55CV3 and what the newest version it can run. You gave me a great start thanks again (NanoScribe)

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are rooted: Just install the apps busy box and terminal emulator. You are good to go afterwards.

See attached Screenshot.[image]